# how to count number of active users in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

We're using kernel version 2.4-20 and we need to count number of active users, in kernel mode. Objective is to change the scheduler, so we are in sched.c, modifying schedule() function.

What we do is to count the users in list_for_each macro.

```
list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head) {
    p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
    if (can_schedule(p, this_cpu)) {
        if (unique(p->uid)) add_new_user(p->uid);
        int weight = goodness(p, this_cpu, prev->active_mm);
        if (weight > c)
            c = weight, next = p;
    }
}
```

which is basically adding unique users to a list. However, we get random results. Is there a concrete way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'random results'?

Comment: At first we counted users in goodness() function, there we had absolutely arbitrary numbers (even though we had 4 users running at the same time, we could get 1 user as result). in sched(), we seem to have consistent values but we are not sure, since sched() is run so frequently, we need to take samples (once in 5000 turns). I guess there is no field in kernel that holds current active users? if there is not, what is the best way to count them? thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I do not know the answer to this. My intention was to point out that the question was not entirely clear. I'd suggest editing this into the question. Good luck!

Comment: So much non-user functionality is actually in user-space libraries ("shared objects") rather than actually inside the kernel that I fear finding out how many users are actually inside the kernel at any given time would be more-or-less random and highly unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try counting the users inside the for_each_task macro. This results in counting the users that have a task which is blocked due to I/O or any other reason. This should provide better results as you can't guarantee being able to count the users who run interactive processes if you use the run queue.

Comment: that makes sense. but we counted users in goodness function first, that might be the cause of random results. I don't have an explanation for that though. For some reason, for_each_task in schedule function works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? who | awk ' { print $1 }' | sort -ud

Comment: I'm in kernel, I cannot use system calls nor terminal programs.